# php simple insert form

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

i'm newbie for PHP and just try simple form but have issue with insert.php page 
first  of all my db consist of 4 record (id ,name ,phonenumber,date) the id column is auto increment page .

i create to display information to page call index php it's work well 
but the problem is insert.php page that page doesn't load and can not  inset value and go to see new insert value in index php page

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_post['name'])){
            $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','interdet');
            $statement =$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO detectives(name)VALUES(?,?)";
            $statement->bind_param('ss',$_POST['name']);
            $statement->execute();
            echo "Done! <a href='index.php'>Go here see new detective </a>";

        }
        else {
            ?>
            <form action="insert.php" method="POST">
            <p>Name : <input type="text" name="name" /> <P>
            <p><input type="submit"/></p>
            </form>
<?php   } ?>
```

Comment: So what about `phonenumber` and `date`? You are not inserting them, do they have default values? or do they allow `NULL`

Comment: is your form and your insert sql in the same page?

Comment: Where is the question? What have you tried to solve the problem? What have you tried to find out, what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but looking at your code, I think everything is ok just I don't understand this line:

```
$statement =$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO detectives(name)VALUES(?,?)";

Prepare opens the bracket ( but doesn't close it)
```

can be this the problem?

Comment: but data not inserting to db

Comment: @ChamaraMadhushanka: Then... why did you accept this answer as correct? Please read my answer, I'm betting that's your problem.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Because nowadays there are too many noobs on SO including the OP

Comment: i accept i feel very happy bez no page error ( page load ) but data isn't insert to db

Answer (score 2):

At first glence, I can tell you that you're attempting to bind two paramters, but you only bind one.

At second glance, you're also missing a closing bracket on your prepare.

```
$statement =$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO detectives(name)VALUES(?,?)");
//                                                               ^^^  ?
$statement->bind_param('ss',$_POST['name']);
//                      ^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ???
```

Comment: @ChamaraMadhushanka: If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Answer (score 0):

You insert in one column "name" but you bind 2 values. I think the correct syntax is:

```
    $statement =$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO detectives(name)VALUES(?)");
    $statement->bind_param('s',$_POST['name']);
    $statement->execute();
```